# Enable CORS for "/health" endpoint in Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-boot-actuator

We want to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for all `GET` requests to the `/health` endpoint provided by Spring Boot Actuator.

We tried adding the following bean without success:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/health").allowedMethods("GET");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a [few properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoint-cors) that can be used to enable CORS for the actuator's endpoints. For example, to allow `GET` requests from `example.com` in Spring Boot 1.x:

```
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=http://example.com
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods=GET
```

and for Spring Boot 2:

```
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=http://example.com
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=GET
```

Comment: this is what we ended up doing, it does it for all actuator endpoints which will work in our case. still didn't find a way to just do it for the /health endpoint though.

Comment: also to note, in order to make it work for all orgins we set `endpoints.cors.allowed-origins: "*"` in the `.yml` file, the quotes around * were important

Comment: @Jon Erickson - you may try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874351/spring-boot-enabling-cors-by-application-properties#56091733

Answer (score 7):

Spring boot 2:

You need to add the allow OPTIONS and allow headers as follows

```html
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=*
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=OPTIONS, GET, POST
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-headers=*
```