# Spring Boot enabling CORS by application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I using Spring Boot API RESTful that get up automatically by your Entities Class. I'm consuming this apiRest from a front-end web app but it gives me this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I'm setting the CORS configuration using the applicantion.properties specified [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html).

My basic configuration is:

```
endpoints.cors.allow-credentials=true
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=*
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods=*
endpoints.cors.allowed-headers=*
```

I have tried different combinations in those variables but still not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I got the answer by myself:

Just add this to application.java

```
  @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: IntelliJ shows that WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is depricated, could solve this by using return new WebMvcConfigurer()

Answer (score 58):

This is not very clear in the official Spring documentation, and it is very easy to be misled by [the official Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoint-cors).

The truth is that you **CANNOT** set the global CORS congfiguration using the application.properties file. You **HAVE TO** use JavaConfig as described by the [*Cors* chapter from Spring *Framework Documentation*](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html#_global_cors_configuration).

Just use the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation on a `@Configuration` class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer` and overrides the `addCorsMappings` method as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://domain2.com")
            .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
            .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
            .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

Comment: From Spring 5 instead of "extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter" use "implements WebMvcConfigurer" (interface with default methods, one of them is addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry))

Answer (score 17):

Spring boot properties prefixed by *endpoints.cors.** are used by Actuator so that's why it will not work with MVC endpoints.

Answer (score 12):

We can move actual cors related urls to application.properties anyway. It works for me with Spring Boot 5.

App.java (main class):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReportsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                String urls = env.getProperty("cors.urls");
                CorsRegistration reg = registry.addMapping("/api/**");
                for(String url: urls.split(",")) {
                    reg.allowedOrigins(url);
                }
            }
        };
    }    
}
```

application.properties:

```
cors.urls=http://localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 6):

You could inject the Strings, should you want to save them in the application.properties

Dev

```
# application-dev.properties
appName.allowedApi=http://localhost:4200
```

Prod

```
# application-prod.properties
appName.allowedApi=https://appname.com
```

And in your WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${appName.allowedApi}")
    private String myAllowedApi;
  
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedOrigins(myAllowedApi);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would enable both the dev and prod origins in both dev and prod. A better solution would be to create an `application.properties` and an `application-dev.properties` and use the same key name in both files.

Comment: Absolutely right @Daly. This is already a while back :) Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Its even simple in spring boot2 , just specify the crossdomain url in the management acutators like this

```
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=http://examaple.com ,http://examaple1.com 
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=GET, POST
```

Comment: This is only for the Actuator endpoints, not your application's own endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

What is worth mentioning is that with newer versions of spring you can add patterns for your allowed origins using `allowedOriginsPattrens` builder method. In this case, you don't need to strictly provide the origins:

```
public class YourConfig implements WebMvConfigurer {
  (...)
    public void addCorsMapping(Corsregistry registry) {
       registry.addMapping(""/your/endpoints/root/**)
         .allowCredentials(true)
         .allowedOriginsPatterns("*.your.domain1.com", "*.your.domain2.com)
        .allowHeaders("*")
        .allowMethods("*");
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess it is allowedHeaders and allowedMethod, right?

Answer (score 3):

In application.property file add origins and headers. Make sure there are no spaces after the comma.

```
allowed.origins = http://localhost:3000,http://192.168.00.00:3000,http://servername:3000
allowed.headers = Content-Type,Authorization,loggedInUserId,Cache-Control,Pragma,Expires
```

WebMvcConfigurer implement file

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Value("${allowed.origins}")
private String allowedOrigins;
@Value("${allowed.headers}")
private String allowedHeaders;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
   
    CorsRegistration reg = registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
    reg.allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins.split(","));
    reg.allowedHeaders(allowedHeaders.split(","));
    }
 
}
```

Comment: i don't understand why spring does not allow us to merely set predefined properties files for these, so that we developer don't have to write more codes. How hard can that be?

Answer (score 2):

Checked with Spring-Boot 2.1.2:

THe first thing is to know what servlet filters are already in place. Servlet filters are supposed to add response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I looked up in my spring logs and decided to add CorsFilter that originally comes from Spring.

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://127.0.0.1:4200");
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("OPTIONS", "GET"));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/actuator/**", config);

    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Since you are injecting CorsFilter - you can easily see what is happening in there. In this case - we are hitting OTHER endpoint than "/actuator/**". No configuration is available for it.

[image]

The above (null) does not mean that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" will not be present. It can be added by a filter other than we injected (e.g if you have controller annotated with @CrossOrigin - the cross-origin header will be added in some other mvc filter, other than our CorsFilter).

In the case below we hit /actuator:

[image]

You can also create your own custom filter that adds header to http-response. I think it is better to use standard approach, but in some debug cases it might be handy to know that by adding a line in your fileter - you can add desired.

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Note that the above contains no conditional checking offered earlier.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just add @CrossOrigin annotation above @RequestMapping.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/{id}")
public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution for doing this for a specific controller using `@CrossOrigin` annotation is:

In controller class:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "${client.url}")
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/foo")
public class FooController {
  ...
}
```

In application.properties:

```
# Client URL
client.url=http://localhost:4200
```

Comment: How do I make add multiple values to the client.url? Something like `client.url=http://localhost:3001,http://localhost:3002`. I tried `"#{'${client.url}'.split(',')}"` but it doesn't work

Comment: I would create multiple properties and set every one of them seperately, e.g.:
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"${client.url.dev}", "${client.url.test}"})
I did a little test and it seems to work fine

Comment: I am actively using this solution with Spring Boot 2.0.5. It seems to me pretty practical and neat. Simply honestly and friendly, I would like to know if I did something wrong to receive a negative vote.

Answer (score 0):

The cors properties is not enough in the app.properties to get it working, but we can simply use it

cors properties with domain placeholder

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      cors:
        allowed-origins: "http://localhost:8080,https://${domain}"
        allowed-methods: "OPTIONS,GET,POST,DELETE,PATCH"
        allowed-headers: "accept,api_key,Authorization,Content-Type,Origin"
        allowed-credentials: true
```

and security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(withDefaults());
        //
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties) {
        var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration());
        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use library for configuring CORS by properties file for Mvc and Flux:
I made library special for this and implementation of this library  long working in productions
[for Spring-web-**MVC** in maven central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:%22io.github.iruzhnikov%22%20AND%20a:%22spring-webmvc-cors-properties-autoconfigure%22)
[for Spring-web-**Flux** in maven central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:%22io.github.iruzhnikov%22%20AND%20a:%22spring-webflux-cors-properties-autoconfigure%22)

### ***Example***

---

add dependency

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.iruzhnikov</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc-cors-properties-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

add to `application.yml` (course you may use default `application.properties`)

```yml
spring:
  web:
    cors:
      enabled: true
      mappings: #spring.web.cors.mappings.<any_name>.<property>: <value>
        anyName: #just any name, just for grouping properties under the same path pattern (not used in internal logic)
          paths: #ant style path pattern, ATTENTION! not ordered, /** pattern override all other pattern
            - /path/to/api
            - /path/to/api/**
          #allowed-origins: "*"
          allowed-methods: GET #Enable override all defaults! If disabled: a lot more from all the controller methods included from the path pattern matches
          #allowed-headers: "*"
          #exposed-headers: ('*' - not-supported)
          #allow-credentials: true
          allowed-origin-patterns: .*
          #max-age: PT30M
```