# How to use a Map in a properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

How to map this in a properties file?

I'm trying to follow [this documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#cors-configuration) on Spring Cloud Gateway

However, we us application.properties.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "https://docs.spring.io"
            allowedMethods:
            - GET
```

I've tried different variations to no avail:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations./**.allowed-origin
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations.[/**].allowed-origin
```

I get an exception:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to bind properties under
>   'spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.cors-configurations.allowed-origins'
>   to org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration:
>
> ```
> Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type
> ```
>
> [org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration]
>
> Action:
>
> Update your application's configuration

Please note that this code is using Spring Cloud Hoxton.M3. I understand that one might assume that the known implementation as per the Spring Guide might be the answer but this is not the case as SC Gateway does not use HttpServlet anymore.

Update:
This works according to Marcos Barbero. Apparently, Eclipse can't understand this data type as a property. For now, you'll have to deal with ignoring the parsing error.

```
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowedOrigins=*
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowedMethods=*
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowCredentials=true
```

Comment: If you folks are skeptical about the behavior you can add a breakpoint for one of the setters in CorsConfiguration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't try it out, but I think you can use it like this:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowedOrigins="https://docs.spring.io"
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowedMethods[0]=GET
```

If it doesn't work, try to remove the square brackets from `[/**]` resulting in `/**`.

Comment: Can you share a sample application somewhere? :)

Comment: You can download a from initializr (2.2.0) with the SC gateway dependency and just add those keys in. It's pretty bare bones since I'm starting out.

Comment: Weird, I just did and the application has started `Started DemoApplication in 1.869 seconds (JVM running for 2.447)`

Comment: Are you using `Hoxton` for Spring Cloud?

Comment: I’m using RC1 and I’ve added the keys I posted above and it worked

Comment: This worked: spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].(other properties). You might want to change your answer to that. Thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can't set these properties using propeties file. Rather use Spring configuration to setup these properties something like below:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/test-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
            }
        };
    }
```

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874351/spring-boot-enabling-cors-by-application-properties) post might be of some help.

Comment: This code is from the older Spring Finchley code. I'm using Hoxton.M3. These classes no longer exist.

Comment: checkout the SO link i shared, it talks about same. But crux is you have to use configuration for CORS not properties.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know how to do that on Hoxton yet otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Worth noting that prior to my transition to SC Gateway, my old code used CorsConfiguration. This caused a NoClassDefinition excemption during startup because SC Gateway no longer uses Http Web Servlet.