# web.cors.allowed-origins in application.properties isn't allowing the CORS for specific urls

Tags: spring-boot, get, cors, spring-boot-2

I'm trying to enable the CORS throughout the app for "http://localhost/4200". Since I'm using Springboot 2 and accord. to its docs, I just have to add this property in application.properties file:

```
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=http://localhost:4200
```

But this doesn't work. Secondly since there is a request I'm making through a restController, for the testing purpose, I tried to add the inline :

```
CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4401")
```

This allowed the flow of data through 4401 port too.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set CORS settings from the application.properties file.
The property management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins is related to Spring Actuator.

If you want to use the setting for a specific endpoint, you can use the @CrossOrigin annotation as you mentioned in your question.

If you want to set a global policy for your application, you can add a configuration class / bean for setting the CORS settings.
See: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors

Related question:
[Spring Boot enabling CORS by application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874351/spring-boot-enabling-cors-by-application-properties/)