# Spring Boot - Multiple Domains from application.properties in @CrossOrigin annotation

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I have Spring Boot application that is deployed to number of environments and as a result needs multiple CORS origins set in order to be accessible from our web application.

This by itself is not a problem as I can provide comma separated list of domains in `@CrossOrigin` annotation.  I also have some controllers that are not supposed to be accessed by our web application, so these would simply not be annotated by `@CrossOrigin`.

For example, here is my `CarController` which needs this annotation and `PartController` which does not need it:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"domain1", "domain2", "domain3, ..."})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/cars")
public class CarController {
   ...
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/parts")
public class PartController {
   ...
}
```

As this list is lengthy, I would like to move the above domains into **application.properties** like:

```
allowed.cors.origins=domain1,domain2,domain3,domain4, ....,domain10
```

I know I can use `@Value(...)` in the class to get value(s) set in `allowed.cors.origins` property.  However, I cannot do that when using an annotation like `@CrossOrigin` on top of my controller.

How can use the values from **application.properties** file inside the `@CrossOrigin` annotation on the `CarsController` above?

**MY SOLUTION**

I accepted below answer from @birca123 but I did not use or test it but it makes sense and it will probably be useful to some.  However, I found out that it is actually possible to reference an **application.properties** setting in an annotation like `@CrossOrigin`.  [Spring Boot enabling CORS by application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42874351/) was helpful, so I am providing the solution I am using now below.

In my **application.properties** set variable:

```
allowed.cors.origins=https://somedomain.com
```

Then you can get this property in both code and annotation like below.

In code, using `@Value` like:

```java
    @Value("${allowed.cors.origins}")
    private List<String> allowedCorsOrigins;
```

In `@CrossOrigin` annotation like:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "${allowed.cors.origins}")
```

So, now my controller looks like:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "${allowed.cors.origins}")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/cars")
public class CarController {
   ...
}
```

Note that I realized I dont need multiple domains so I moved away from that but it should work the same way.  I tested it with using `@Value("${allowed.cors.origins}") private List<String> allowedCorsOrigins` in code and it worked.  I havent tried it in `@CorsOrigins` annotation but it should work.  If not, the accepted answer should work but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global CORS configuration, as shown below, instead of annotating controllers with `@CrossOrigin`. Multiple CORS mappings can be declared to cover all endpoints needing cross-origin request handling.

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Value("${allowed.cors.origins}")
  String[] allowedOrigins;

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addMapping("/v1/cars/**")
        .allowedMethods("*")
        .allowedHeaders("*")
        .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
    registry
        .addMapping("/another-cors-mapping/**")
        .allowedMethods("*")
        .allowedHeaders("*")
        .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
     // Add more mappings...
  }
}
```

For reference: [Spring docs - CORS - Global Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-cors-global)

Comment: Thanks but in this case, all of my controllers are getting CORS access by default.  I have some controllers needing CORS while others do not need it.  Like in my post above `CarController` needs CORS, but `PartController` does not need it.

Comment: You can specify mapping multiple times with different arguments of the `addMapping` method to enable cross-origin request handling for the path pattern matching the controllers needing CORS.

Comment: Mind updating the answer how to do that?  Much appreciated

Comment: Thank you.  I am using solution as per my update but I think your solution is also good.